# Projectile motion - calculate landing angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> A projectile is launched at a $45^\circ$ angle, aiming for a target at a distance of 15 feet  away from, and $2$ feet **below** the starting position.

I'm looking for equations to determine:

- The initial velocity of the projectile required to hit the target
- The angle at which the projectile hits the target

I'm particularly interested in learning if there are equations to solve this, as I'm interested in plugging in different distance/height offsets in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We can first find the angle since the initial and final velocities are not given, while the initial displacement are given as X = Y = 0 and the final displacement as X = 4.57 m and Y = 0.61 m.

The goal is to eliminate the initial unknown velocities where
$$v_x = v_i\cos(\theta)$$
$$v_y = v_i\sin(\theta)$$
To do this we use equations
$$x = v_i\cos(\theta)t$$
$$y = v_i\sin(\theta)t-\frac12gt^2$$
Substituting for $v_i$ we get have
$$y = \tan(\theta)x-\frac 12 g\left(\frac x{v_i\cos\theta}\right)^2$$
We can use this equation to solve for $\theta$ which is the angle at which the target is hit.

Given $\theta$ we can find $v_i$ using $$y = v_i\sin(\theta)t-\frac12gt^2$$

Comment: Thanks very much, but I don't see how to rearrange the substituted equation (y=tan...) to give the angle (Apologies, my math is pretty rusty!).

Comment: The equation y =  is a transcendental one which must be solved iteratively for theta, given values for x and y

Answer (score 0):

Start with the kinematics in *x* and *y* coordinates

$$\begin{aligned} x &= \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} t \\ y & = \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2 \end{aligned}$$

To hit the target at $x$ you need $t =\frac{x \sqrt{2}}{v}$ time. At this time the vertical position is

$$ y = \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{x\sqrt{2}}{v} \right) - \frac{1}{2} g \left( \frac{x \sqrt{2}}{v} \right)^2 = x - \frac{g x^2}{v^2} $$

Solve the above for $v$ the initial velocity.

Once you have the initial velocity calculate the slope by calculating the velocity components in the *x* and *y* directions as a function of time.

$$\begin{align} \dot{x}(t) &= \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \dot{y} (t)&= \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}} - g t \end{align}$$

and $$\mbox{(slope)} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = 1 - \frac{g t \sqrt{2}}{v}$$

Comment: Just for a check I get the angle to be below 60° and above 50° in a negative direction.

Comment: I'm getting -55, so that seems to fit your range - thanks!

Just to check, is the square root of 2 part for the formulae above the offset for the height? That is, if the target was 4 feet below the starting location, would I change these formulas to take the square root of 4 where it was previously the square root of 2?

Comment: the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from the 45° angle of launch. Did you plug in the final time $t=\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{v}$ and then the launch speed $v$ to get the angle. My result was between -50° and -52° actually. Also remember to $\theta=\arctan\mbox{(slope)}$

Comment: Still not getting there - maybe we can check where I'm making my error.

I get v as 20.64404,
t = 1.03,
x(t) = 14.60533
y(t) = -1693.44

Comment: I might have screwed up the units. I blame on the idiotic feet-inches debacle. For the target $(x,y)=(15,-2)$ I get $$\begin{aligned} t & =\sqrt{ \frac{2(x-y)}{g}} & v & = x \sqrt{\frac{g}{x-y}} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have it to there (see previous post). Problem is beyond that point - calculating the angle using these values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32966/discussion-between-x-and-ja72).

Comment: I think there may be a mistake in the formulas here - should the square root of 2 part in fact be 1/sqrt(2) (i.e. cos(45 degrees) or sin(45 degrees)?)

Comment: No the square root divides $v$ always because of $v \cos 45° = \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Your calculations are not wrong becuz feet and inches since all your work is in decimal feet.  The formula above for y-dot(t) is incorrect.  y-dot(t) = v/sqrt(2)-gt.

Comment: Good catch ... I fixed it